# gradle mysql dependency syncs but doesnt work

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

So I am adding a mysql dependency to my `build.gradle`, and it syncs perfect, but the problem is that I cant use the dependency code.
for instance, I added mysql.jar as a dependency, and it loaded, but trying to import com.mysql.jdbc.driver wont work.

Notice that Im using libgdx library

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Baladiya"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }

}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile files("libs/mysql.jar")
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile files("libs/mysql.jar")
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile files("libs/mysql.jar")
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile files("libs/mysql.jar")
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile files("libs/mysql.jar")    
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

My import error: 
[image: import error]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need mysql.jar in the first place? Judging by what you showed us, you need just a driver - simply import a driver from jcenter or maven central for example:

`compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'`

into the core.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about how many projects have `libs/mysql.jar`, but if you include `compile files("libs/mysql.jar")` dependency under each project, you need the jar under the corresponding project like this:

```
desktop/
|- src/
|- libs/mysql.jar
android/
|- src/
|- libs/mysql.jar
ios/
|- src/
|- libs/mysql.jar
html/
|- src/
|- libs/mysql.jar
core/
|- src/
|- libs/mysql.jar
```

Since you have already require `desktop`, `android`, `ios`, `html` projects depending on `core`, 
so the dependency of `compile files("libs/mysql.jar")` is actually redundant,
you only need it to be included in `core/`.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I removed the dependency from all, but kept it in core, and still, the same error

Comment: @Liwaa, can you do `./gradlew clean build --debug` for me

Comment: what about `gradle clean build --debug`, gradlew is wrapper gradle.

Comment: i did some fixes, and the gradlew command worked, but the error persists

Comment: New error, when i typed ./gradlew clean, then ./gradlew build, this happened:
https://pastebin.com/ETjSMaHE